# Why does this Python docstring not have newlines in the VS Code hover info?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have this docstring:

```py
def get_crypto_price(crypto: str, currency: str, max_attempts: int = 3) -> float | None:
   """
   Retrieves the price of a cryptocurrency in a specified currency using the CoinGecko API.

   Args:
      crypto (str): The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').  
      currency (str): The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd').  
      max_attempts (int): The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).

   Returns:
      float | None: The price of the cryptocurrency in the specified currency, or None if the price could not be retrieved.
   """
```

But it shows up like this in VS Code, with no newline between the currency and max_attempts lines:
[image: docsctring context menu]

How do I get the max_attempts line to be on a new line in the hover info?

Answer (score 2):

Python docs generally use [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html) as their markup format. What you've written with your "Args" and "Returns" are [definition lists](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#definition-lists), where paragraphs in the definition section are separated by *empty lines*, and two lines in the definition section with no empty line between them are treated as part of the same paragraph. So what I find actually surprising is the fact that VS Code puts a newline in the hover info between the first two lines of your "Args" definition section (and I don't know why it does that. Either it's a bug, or I'm missing something).

If you want to do things the way Python recommends for [Sphinx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphinx_(documentation_generator)) usage, see https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/restructuredtext/domains.html#info-field-lists, https://devguide.python.org/documentation/markup/#quick-reference, https://devguide.python.org/documentation/markup/#directives, and https://devguide.python.org/documentation/markup/#information-units.

Which would look something like this:

```py
"""
Retrieves the price of a cryptocurrency in a specified currency using the CoinGecko API.

:param crypto: The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').  
:param currency: The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd').  
:param max_attempts: The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).
:return: The price of the cryptocurrency in the specified currency, or None if the price could not be retrieved.
"""
```

If you don't care about the Sphinx-friendly way of writing documentation, you can just turn your definition section into a [bullet list](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#bullet-lists). Ex.

```
Args:
    - crypto (str): The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').
    - currency (str): The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd').
    - max_attempts (int): The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).
```

Comment: I went with bullet list. Thanks!

Comment: @GollyJer you're welcome! If this answer helped you, consider marking it as "accepted" (check mark button)

Comment: This was my favorite alternative of the provided answers, but I don't think any of them answer the question exactly. In this case, I think it's best to let the voting be the judge.

Answer (score 0):

As @user said, Python documentation use reStructuredText and the it looks like this:

```py
from typing import Union

def get_crypto_price(crypto: str, currency: str, max_attempts: int = 3) -> Union[float, None]:
   """
   Retrieves the price of a cryptocurrency in a specified currency using the CoinGecko API.

   :param crypto: The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').  
   :param currency: The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd').  
   :param max_attempts: The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).
   :return: The price of the cryptocurrency in the specified currency, or None if the price could not be retrieved.
   """
```

**Notes**

- The type annotations are not included in the docstring
- As a matter of style, I use `Union[float, None]` to denote the return types

Answer (score 0):

##### Method one

Use `\n` newline at the end of a sentence

```py
def get_crypto_price(crypto: str, currency: str, max_attempts: int = 3) -> float | None:
   """
   Retrieves the price of a cryptocurrency in a specified currency using the CoinGecko API.

   Args:
      crypto (str): The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').  
      currency (str): The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd'). \n 
      max_attempts (int): The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).

   Returns:
      float | None: The price of the cryptocurrency in the specified currency, or None if the price could not be retrieved.
   """
```

[image]

##### Method two

Add spaces at the beginning of the sentence

```py
def get_crypto_price(crypto: str, currency: str, max_attempts: int = 3) -> float | None:
   """
   Retrieves the price of a cryptocurrency in a specified currency using the CoinGecko API.

   Args:
      crypto (str): The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').  
      currency (str): The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd'). 
       max_attempts (int): The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).

   Returns:
      float | None: The price of the cryptocurrency in the specified currency, or None if the price could not be retrieved.
   """
```

[image]

##### Method three

Add a blank line between every two lines (*can be used in conjunction with method two*)

```py
def get_crypto_price(crypto: str, currency: str, max_attempts: int = 3) -> float | None:
   """
   Retrieves the price of a cryptocurrency in a specified currency using the CoinGecko API.

   Args:
      crypto (str): The cryptocurrency to retrieve the price for (e.g., 'bitcoin').  
      currency (str): The currency to retrieve the price in (e.g., 'usd'). 
      
      max_attempts (int): The maximum number of attempts to make before giving up (default: 3).

   Returns:
      float | None: The price of the cryptocurrency in the specified currency, or None if the price could not be retrieved.
   """
```

[image]

Comment: all of these methods have spacing artifacts :/

Comment: your answer is the same.

Comment: really? what I wrote in my answer doesn't have spacing artifacts for me, and each line render separately. Does it not for you?

Comment: If you format the three lines at the same time, there is no problem. You could try adding formatting to only one of the lines (only the last line was formatted in my answer).

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I ended up going with the bulleted list.