# Reference Section to Python Google Docstring

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docstring

Does anyone know of a good way to include references in a python docstring that follows the google formatting?  I'm writing a series of fluid property generators. I wanted a way to easily document a reference to the correlation or equations I am using so someone could go read about them or see where they came from. I did the following but it is not properly formatted in VS Code. Does anyone know of any other methods?

```
def viscosity(self) -> float: 
    """Live oil viscosity, cP    
    
    Return the live oil viscosity, cP.
    Requires pressure and temperature condition to previously be set.

    Args:
        None

    Returns:
        uoil (float): live oil viscosity, cP

    References:
        Fundamental Principles of Reservoir Engineering, B.Towler (2002) Page 23
        Correlations for Fluid Physical Property... Vasquez and Beggs (1980)
    """
    
    pabs = self._pressa  # absolute pressure
    temp = self.temp  # deg F
    oil_api = self.oil_api
```

Comment: Are you asking how to force VSCode to display the two references on separate lines? What do you mean by "it is not properly formatted"?

Comment: Yes Pranav, separate lines with the correct indentation.

Comment: Refer to this question： https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76009595/why-does-this-python-docstring-not-have-newlines-in-the-vs-code-hover-info/76010897#76010897

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most ways I've found to add a newline to the displayed code hint are quite clunky. For example:

Adding a `\n` after the first reference results in a wider gap between the two references:

```
    """
    ...
    References:
        Fundamental Principles of Reservoir Engineering, B.Towler (2002) Page 23\n
        Correlations for Fluid Physical Property... Vasquez and Beggs (1980)
    ...
    """
```

[image: larger space between lines]

Adding a space before the second reference causes the first character of both lines to be unaligned:

```
    """
    ...
    References:
        Fundamental Principles of Reservoir Engineering, B.Towler (2002) Page 23
         Correlations for Fluid Physical Property... Vasquez and Beggs (1980)
    ...
    """
```

[image: Space before Correlations]

---

You could instead use an unordered list to format your references:

```
def viscosity(self) -> float: 
    """Live oil viscosity, cP    
    
    Return the live oil viscosity, cP.
    Requires pressure and temperature condition to previously be set.

    Args:
        None

    Returns:
        uoil (float): live oil viscosity, cP

    References:
        - Fundamental Principles of Reservoir Engineering, B.Towler (2002) Page 23
        - Correlations for Fluid Physical Property... Vasquez and Beggs (1980)
    """
    pass
```

In the code hint, this unordered list appears like so:
[image: screenshot of VSCode hint]

Comment: Thank you for this reply. This seems like a good solution.

Comment: @KaelinEllis You should accept the answer by clicking on tick icon ✅ which is at left of the answer, so that community can understand that the question has been answered.